# Why does my CheerpJ webpage show the loading screen yet doesn't work?

Tags: java, html, swing, cheerpj

I'm new to CheerpJ, So I read and followed the getting started tutorial. no matter what I did, however, I couldn't get it to work. the webpage would just show the CheerpJ loading screen (the rotating circle) and stay there. How do I fix that and get my app to run?

Answer (score 1):

You can find common mistakes in CheerpJ FAQs: https://github.com/leaningtech/cheerpj-meta/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#my-application-compiled-with-cheerpj-does-not-work-and-i-just-see-the-cheerpj-runtime-ready-on-the-top-of-the-screen-whats-going-on

If those suggestions do not help, please add more information to your question:

1. The HTML code used to integrated CheerpJ
2. Any network errors you can see in the Dev Tools network tab.

The most common mistake by far is misunderstanding how the CheerpJ virtual filesystem work, so I would also recommend to read this: https://github.com/leaningtech/cheerpj-meta/wiki/File-System-support#app-mount-point